Kafka, how configure StatelessBackOffPolicy
I need your help because i want to configure a custom StatelessBackOffPolicy but i can't figure how.
I checked on internet but the samples are all using retryTemplate and retryTemplate is now deprecated so i can't use it. Can you help me?
This is the actual configuration of my listener :
@KafkaListener(
      topics = "${topicName}",
      containerFactory = "topicContainerFactory")
  @RetryableTopic(
      kafkaTemplate = "topicKafkaTemplate",
      attempts = "4",
      backoff =
          @Backoff(
              delayExpression =
                  "${application.delayExpression}"),
      autoCreateTopics = "false",
      include = {
        RetrayableException.class
      },
      topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)

i want to know how to configure my custom backoff

import org.springframework.retry.backoff.StatelessBackOffPolicy;

public class SocketBackOffPolicy extends StatelessBackOffPolicy {

  private int increment;

  public EquipmentShipmentBackOffPolicy(int initialInterval, int increment) {
    this.increment = increment;
  }

  @Override
  public void doBackOff() {
    try {
      if (increment > 2) {
        Thread.sleep(600);
      } else {
        Thread.sleep(200);
      }
      increment = increment + 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      increment = increment + 1;
    }
  }

}


